# describe the region created by transforming $\operatorname{Re}(z) >\frac{1}{2}$ by $z^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

as the question says: 
describe the region created by transforming $\operatorname{Re}(z) >\frac{1}{2}$ by $z^2$ 
my thoughts: I've started by creating an equation and squaring it but got nothing useful, bashed my head against it for a while. must be overcomplicating it...

$$ r\cos(\theta) > 0.5 $$
$$ r^2\cos(2\theta) > 0.25$$
I don't really know how to continue, I managed to expand it by reconverting to cartesian but got nonsense results.

Comment: by nonsense I mean either the theta and the x requirements conflict, or I got a true statement that I could've got by focusing on x solely and nothing more.

Comment: The image of the boundary of the region ($\operatorname{Re}(z) =\frac{1}{2}$) under the $z^2$-transformation is indeed a parabola. There is probably no simple way to describe the image of the original region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$.

Then $w=z^2\implies u+iv=(x+iy)^2\implies u=x^2-y^2, v=2xy$

Considering the boundary of the region, where $x=\frac12$, then
$$u=\frac14-y^2, v=y$$

$$\implies v^2=\frac14-u$$

This is a parabola whose line of symmetry is the real axis and whose vertex is at $w=\frac14$.

Testing a point in the original region $x>\frac12$, the image of $z=1$, for example, is $w=1$. So the image region is the area outside the parabola to the right of the curve. This can be described by the inequality $u>\frac14-v^2$.